# Is json-patch supported in restclient?

Tags: c#, restsharp, json-patch

I am having trouble in using POST method and JSON-Patch operations (Please refer to RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) in RestSharp's RestClient.  AddBody() contains something like this:

```
request.AddBody(new { op = "add", path = "/Resident", value = "32432" });
```

It errors out. I don't know how to pass `json-patch` operations in the body. I have tried everything I could. Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using parameters instead of AddBody?

Comment: It seems I have overcome this problem but the question is still valid because my error description has changed now. The error description is as following:{"type":"error","status":415,"code":"unsupported_media_type","help_url":"http:\/\/\/#errors","message":"Content-Type must be application\/json-patch+json","request_id":"1953d8ac6"} I get unsupported_media_type error and error is raised in the restclient.execute() method. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Prix, Yes I had tried parameters and that had not worked but anyway I am able to pass the operations in the body now but the issue is related to json-patch. It seems execute() method does not support json-patch response. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This is an improved version of Scott's answer. I did not like querying the parameters and RestSharp provides a way to set the name directly with **AddParameter**

```
var request = new RestRequest(myEndpoint, Method.PATCH);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json-patch+json");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
var body = new
{
  op = "add",
  path = "/Resident",
  value = "32432"
}
request.AddParameter("application/json-patch+json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);

var response = restClient.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var request = new RestRequest(myEndpoint, Method.PATCH);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json-patch+json");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(
    new
    {
        op = "add",
        path = "/Resident",
        value = "32432"
});

request.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Type == ParameterType.RequestBody).Name = "application/json-patch+json";

var response = restClient.Execute(request);
```